# Python: UTF-8 german special chars

Tags: python, utf

I'm searching for files in a python script and storing the filepathes.
The problem is, that in some cases there are special chars like ö ä ü 
inside (UTF-8 Table hex U+00C4 U+00D6 U+00DC etc.)
When I print the path with "print" it is shown correctly. When I use this
string for sending it to os.system() the special chars are escaped out and
getting an UTF error.

ErrorMsg:

```
cp -nv /home/rainer/Arbeitsfläche/Videofiles/A047C001_130226_R1WV.mov /media/rainer/LinuxData
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Clipfinder.py", line 254, in <module>
    copyProcess(sourcedir,destdir,cliplist)
  File "Clipfinder.py", line 205, in copyProcess
    os.system(copycmd)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Thx for help !
rainer

```
copycmd = "cp -nv " + pathtoFile_src + " " + destdir
print copycmd
os.system(copycmd)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `encode` to convert unicode to byte string:

```
os.system(copycmd.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: awesome! Thx for the hint!!! its working now... forgot the old command inside, so i got the error again... now its fine!!!!

Comment: Now it's to deal with whitespace chars. cp is cutting up the command there.

Comment: I'm escaping the white-chars with the replace function which works fine. But I have another problem now. When I'm adding a string with special chars into a list getting an error: Scanning Source Directory /home/rainer/Arbeitsfläche/Videofiles test for Files. This can take some time!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Clipfinder_RAW.py", line 346, in <module>
    copyProcess(sourcedir,destdir,cliplist)
  File "Clipfinder_RAW.py", line 238, in copyProcess
    found_srcdirs.encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Before writing it into the list: /home/rainer/Arbeitsfläche/Videofiles test/A051R1WV/A051C001_130227_R1WV.mov and then when its in list: '/home/rainer/Arbeitsfl\xc3\xa4che/Videofiles test/A051R1WV'

Comment: @rainer your should decode string before encoding (you already have encoded byte string):
`print '/home/rainer/Arbeitsfl\xc3\xa4che/Videofiles test/A051R1WV'.decode('utf-8')
/home/rainer/Arbeitsfläche/Videofiles test/A051R1WV`

Comment: I'm getting this error then: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: when I read the list with: for entries in found_dirs: print entries I'm getting the correct output. with: print stringlist[0:] its not decoded.

Comment: @rainer you can post another question, put exception traceback and code in which you got exception in it